# Ctrl key not detected in Terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, stty

I have a problem with my Mac Terminal. It is no longer able to detect the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, so I can't use anymore shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop a running task, because when I do the terminal echoes only the "c" character.

I tried with `stty -a` and the intr seems to be ok:

```
speed 9600 baud; 22 rows; 80 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe -echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr -ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Any idea on how to solve it?